# How to calculate number of transactions within a specific range

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anybody help on how to calculate number of transactions within this range for last year sales using TSQL. I don't have a clue on how to populate that range and link it with my sales total in the database

```
0.01- 5.00,
5.001 -10.00,
10.01 - 15.00
```

I have tried to use this code below,

```
SELECT COUNT (*) as Nooftransactions, Floor (Amount)/5 As Range, Convert(Varchar(max), (5*Floor(Linetotal/5))) +'0.01' + '-' + Convert(Varchar(max), (5*floor(Linetotal/5) +5))) + '0.00' as Rangesplit 
Group by Amount,Floor (Amount)/5 , Convert(Varchar(max), (5*Floor(Linetotal/5))) +'0.01' + '-' + Convert(Varchar(max), (5*floor(Linetotal/5) +5))) + '0.00' 
Order Amount
```

Comment: Hi you're going to need to add a ton of information here.  We need info on your schema, or the table and column names and the relationships between tables.  We need some sample data, something you've tried and your desired output.
It would be really helpful to tell us what kind of SQL you are using, your RMDBS, MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle etc

Comment: Okay thanks, here is what I have tried to use below;

Comment: I use Sql 2016,

Comment: I have tried to use this code below,  SELECT COUNT (*)  as Nooftransactions,  Floor (Amount)/5 As Range,  Convert(Varchar(max), (5*Floor(Linetotal/5))) +'0.01' + '-' + Convert(Varchar(max), (5*floor(Linetotal/5) +5))) + '0.00' as Rangesplit Group by Amount,Floor (Amount)/5 ,  Convert(Varchar(max), (5*Floor(Linetotal/5))) +'0.01' + '-' + Convert(Varchar(max), (5*floor(Linetotal/5) +5))) + '0.00' Order Amount

Comment: I have used the above query but not calculating the amount with 5.00 in the range of 0.01 -5.00 instead calculating the amount of 5.00 in the range of 5.001 -10.00. I think the floor is interfering with the results.is there anyway I can populate the range and link it with amount in my database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of

```
select ranges.lo, ranges.hi,
    count(*) as [number of transactions]
from transactions t
join ( 
  values (0.01, 5.00), (5.001, 10.00), (10.01, 15.00) 
) ranges(lo, hi)
on t.value between ranges.lo and ranges.hi
group by ranges.lo, ranges.hi
order by ranges.lo;
```

Adjust according to the real table structure.

Comment: I don't have  the table specifying the ranges in my database. I have to create those ranges and must be within this range 0.01 - 5.00, 5.01-10.00..... 195.01 - 200 for the last year transactions.

Comment: How do I populate the values in subtlety of your join query.

Comment: @user7363526 Serg is showing you how to create the `ranges` table inside your SQL code.  All you have to do is add the extra ranges in the `values` section.  He has up to (10.01, 15.00).  You just have to add in the rest up to (195.01, 200.00).

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I have tested the code, it works fine. I never knew I could specify values to populate my range with that method. Am seeing the code first time Please any recommendation to improve my TSQL skills. I would appreciate.

Comment: Please any recommendation to improve my TSQL code  @serg

Comment: Please any recommendation to improve my TSQL querying writing skills as am seeing how to populate ranges without using looping but with values

Comment: You may want to read about Table Value Constructor here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx